# Can I wire an 8pin double case fan into 2 x 4pin fan headers, or USB?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan, wiring

I have 2 x [Delta 92x38mm EFB0912HHE Triple Blade High Speed Case Fan - Sleeved](https://www.performance-pcs.com/fans-accessories/92-100mm-fans/delta-92x38mm-efb0912hhe-triple-blade-high-speed-case-fan-sleeved-efb0912hhe.html), which both have 4 wires which are spliced into an 8-pin connector, but only using 6 of the pins (2 are sharing 2 wires each). I've searched around for 8pin connectors but it seems to be a dead technology. My end goal is to use these to blow air on seedlings, so I need a USB output. Can anyone suggest how best to do this?

Feasibly if I got a couple of [female 4pin heads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08HYSHFQZ), I could unwire the cables from out of the 8pin and into 2x4pins then use [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081K8LBH3)?

This is then running me $17... I should just buy something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09NTG81WS) and forget about all this wiring nonsense and chuck these mega old fans that I got free, into eWaste, right?

Photo album [here](https://imgur.com/a/k1zv0NF).